# Count over all n-bits binary words so that on each turn a bit is either turned on or turned off

Tags: algorithm, math

I know that there are 2**n options for an n-bits word.
I want to know if one can count over all the options so that in every turn a single bit is either turned on or turned off.

Comment: You mean, like in [Gray Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a [Gray Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code).

Comment: He is looking for a number of possible gray coding, not just a gray code.

Comment: Replaced "the" with "a". More precise indeed.